# Data Constructor taking any Numeric type as an argument

Tags: haskell, ghc

I was wondering if one could create a data constructor which instead of taking a specific type could take any of a given class.

So instead of

```
data Container = ContainerI Int | ContainerF Float
```

Something like

```
Container::(Num a)=>a
data Container = Container a
```

Comment: Yes, you can do it with some GHC extensions. This is what's called an "existential type", and you can find several good explanations of what they are and why you might want to use them online if you google the term. Eg there is [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types) in the Haskell wikibook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you're asking with an [existentially-quantified data constructor](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/existential_quantification.html), like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Container = forall a. Num a => Container a
```

But as [John F. Miller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67944558/7509065) explains, this probably isn't what you actually want. Instead, just do `data Container a = Container a` and then declare functions like `f :: Num a => Container a -> _whatever`.

Comment: I can't see any way to concretely use that existential type. If `x,y :: Container` we can not sum them. At best, we can sum `x` with itself or with constants. The same holds for other operators, including `(==)` and `(<)`. We can't even print that number. At best, we can perform a check such as `polinomial(x) > 0`, and possible little else, but I can't see anything else which is truly meaningful, given that we can never involve another `y`.

Comment: @chi actually that's not even related to what I had asked for.
I may not have explained myself right to be honest. As I want to create a List with multiple instances of that data type, possibly taking different numbertypes your answer joseph satisfies my question the most. Thank!

Answer (score 6):

Not in standard Haskell.  The normal way to achieve this is to leave `Container` fully generic, then require `(Num a) => Container a` in functions where it is important. The type checkers will prevent code which tries to use a `Container` with an unsupported type from compiling.

If you really want to be extra cautious about it you can keep the actual constructor off the export list an only provide functions that have `(Num a)` as an export, but that is usually not required.

As an example, look at [`Data.Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Set.html). The reality is that for `Set a` to work as intended you will need an `Eq a` instance.  But that restriction is only required in functions that manipulate a `Set`, not the definition of [`Set a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Set.html#t:Set) itself.